# How to pass multiple videos button onclick event in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

call API using `fetch` and get response in console and assign values to table header.
after that creating one button in react js. Each button have one video URL which is got from API response

API response:

```
Camera_Number:"Camera_1"
Group_Name: "Group_1"
Video_Name: "http://localhost:4000/video/0"

Camera_Number:"Camera_2"
Group_Name: "Group_2"
Video_Name: "http://localhost:4000/video/1"
```

I stored this response in `useState` and pass this usestate response to video player source

```
        const actionButton = (params) => {
        setVideoName(response.videoName); //  How to update videoName here
        setOpen(true);
        };

        const [videoName, setVideoName] = useState([]);
        const [response, setResponse] = useState([]);

        headerName: "Actions",
        field: "Video_Name",
        cellRendererFramework: (params) => (
          <div>
            <Button
              variant="contained"
              onClick={() => actionButton(params)}
            >
              Play
            </Button>
          </div>
```

Above code shows assign video_name to `Actions` header then I created one button. when I click one button, all of the videos open in one window and play all videos. But  I want it so that only that certain video that was clicked would show.

```
 <DialogContent>
            {response.map(({ Video_Name }) => (
              <iframe
                width="420"
                height="315"
                title="videos"
                src={Video_Name}
              />
            ))}
          </DialogContent>
```

How to resolve this issue using react-hooks.

for more details and code reference

> https://github.com/iamharry-dev/modal_popup

how to create index for video and pass videos to video player source. when i click that button certain video that was clicked would show.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use the click handler of the button. You cannot get row data with that.

Add a `colId` to column definition for actions. Then handle the `onCellClicked` action of the grid. You can get the row data using `params.node.data`.

```
const [videoName, setVideoName] = useState("");

function onCellClicked(params) {
    // maps to colId: "action" in columnDefs,
    if (params.column.colId === "action") {
      // set videoName for the row
      setVideoName(params.node.data.Video_Name);
      setOpen(true);
    }
}

// grid config
<AgGridReact
  ...
  rowData={response}
  onCellClicked={onCellClicked}>
</AgGridReact>

// access videoName in dialog content
<DialogContent>
 {/* <iframe width="420" height="315" title="videos" src={id} /> */}
 <div>{videoName}</div>
</DialogContent>
```

[Codesand box Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-zhukovsky-gt4mln?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Answer (score 0):

Update answer:
First, you have to install [json-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-loader)

```
npm install --save-dev json-loader
```

After that, You can use dynamically import.
(code demo using React Hooks, do the same with class component)

```
import Record from './db.json'
// Syntax like:
// {
//     "Company_Name": "Fraction Analytics Limited",
//     "Floor Number": "Ground_Floor",
//     "Group_Name": "Group_1",
//     "Camera_Number": "Camera_2",
//     "Video_Name": "./videos/video1.mp4"
//   }

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [video, setVideo] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(Record)
        import(Record.Video_Name).then(res =>
            setVideo(res)
        )
    }, [Record])


    if (!video)
        return <></>
    return (
        <DialogContent>
            <iframe width="420" height="315" title='video'
                src={video}>
            </iframe>
        </DialogContent>
    )
}
```

Comment: You have to JSON.parse(). And do the same thing as my answer